# Improving speed of or substitution for pandas groupby and apply statement

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a medium-sized dataframe of a few million rows, and I am finding that summing a column by group is very slow. I use the following code:

```
# Function to sum costs and utility for each patient
def calculate_on_group(x):
    return pd.Series(x.sum(), index=x.index)

summary_df['cost'] = output_df.groupby(['id', 'run'])['cost'].apply(calculate_on_group)
```

This is because I have a lot of groups. For each value of `run`, there are 10000 different values for `id`, i.e. 10000 groups for each value of run. And `run` itself contains several hundred different values. Both columns are integers.

I have read that it is best to try not use the combination of `groupby()` and `apply` altogether with medium-sized data and a lot of groups, but I have not figured out what to use instead. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the pandas [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) method, which will be much more efficient as it will vectorize all computations at once.

When you define your own aggregating function (`calculate_on_group` here), it is called on each subgroup independently, which is very slow in Python. Always use vectorized operations when possible.

The snippet below runs in a couple of seconds on my laptop.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10_000_000
output_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": np.random.randint(10_000, size=n),
    "run": np.random.randint(1000, size=n),
    "cost": np.random.random(size=n)
})

summary_df = output_df.groupby(["id", "run"])["cost"].sum()
```

You may want to read the [pandas docs on grouping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) and especially [this paragraph](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) on C-based aggregation methods to avoid these performance issues in the future.